Как сделать фильтры по ячейкам в Excel?
У меня есть лист "Отчеты", там заполняются и содержаться данные без фильтра.
Есть лист "Отчеты Фильтры", мне нужно сделать на ней фильтрацию.
Мне нужно в самом вверху указать нужное значение нужному полю и автоматически происходит поиск и фильтрация из листа "Отчеты"
сразу по всем указанным параметрам. Все значения также должны выводиться автоматически. Растягивать формулы не нужно. Можно использовать макросы.
[


=ЕСЛИ(I11 <> "";СМЕЩ(Отчет!A$1;ПОИСКПОЗ(I11; УНИК(Отчет!I:I);0)-1;0);"")


Я не могу использовать стандартные средства Эксель.
Нужен именно такой фильтр
